# C++ polymorphic ring buffer

Tags: c++, circular-buffer

Is there a library that would allow me to store objects of common base type in a buffer supporting enqueue and dequeue? That's really all I need, I don't need O(1) access to each element. It would be allowed that each object can have a different size (a polymorphic ring buffer).
I could use `vector` of pointers of base type, but that seems to me as an overkill. If I use this sort of a ring buffer, I won't have to allocate separate memory for each object.

Comment: What's wrong with `vector`? What makes you think it's overkill? The solution you suggest looks OK to me. BTW library requests are OT.

Comment: The vector solution does not sound that bad. A library would probably do something similar and you need an additional library.

Comment: You cand think about boost [poly_collection](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/poly_collection.html), it is a better solution than `vector` because allocate contiguously same class elements and it  is ready specifically for polymorphic usage.

Comment: @JTejedor that seem nice, but I cannot find if it can preserve the order of all inserted elements (in a FIFO manner)

Comment: @Adam I think poly_collection warrants fifo order in its segments (allocation of the same class because it is a vector), but, due `std::map` is used to store each segments, I think that could be a problem. Make a fast test to eliminate any doubt. Sorry if I can not help more

Comment: What do you mean by its "overkill" to use `std::vector` of pointers?

Comment: @PasserBy I don't need the O(1) access to every element. The O(1) access implies that the vector cannot store the objects of variable size directly as values, but needs to allocate memory for each object separately in addition to storing an array of pointers to them. I don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@JTejedor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693119/c-polymorphic-ring-buffer?noredirect=1#comment82345389_47693119), [boost poly collection](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/poly_collection.html) solves your problem quite directly.

If for some reason you don't like boost, a simplistic solution with `std::variant` can be concocted

```
template<typename Base, typename... Derived>
struct poly
{
    std::variant<Base, Derived...> var;

    template<typename... Args>
    poly(Args&&... args) : var{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}

    auto& get()
    {
        auto id = [](auto& v) -> Base& { return v; };
        return std::visit(id, var);
    }

    operator Base&() { return get(); }
};
```

And use it as

```
struct B {};
struct D1 : B {};
struct D2 : B { int i; };

void foo()
{
    using poly_t = poly<B, D1, D2>;

    std::vector<poly_t> vec;
    vec.push_back(B{});
    vec.push_back(D1{});
    vec.push_back(D2{});

    B& ref = vec.back();
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/q5hfZd)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Boost.Circular Buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/circular_buffer.html). Instead of `int` in example you may store pointers `YourInterfaceClass*` or `std::shared_ptr< YourInterfaceClass >`.

```
// Create a circular buffer with a capacity for 3 integers.
boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(3);

// Insert threee elements into the buffer.
cb.push_back(1);
cb.push_back(2);
cb.push_back(3);

int a = cb[0];  // a == 1
int b = cb[1];  // b == 2
int c = cb[2];  // c == 3

// The buffer is full now, so pushing subsequent
// elements will overwrite the front-most elements.

cb.push_back(4);  // Overwrite 1 with 4.
cb.push_back(5);  // Overwrite 2 with 5.

// The buffer now contains 3, 4 and 5.
a = cb[0];  // a == 3
b = cb[1];  // b == 4
c = cb[2];  // c == 5

// Elements can be popped from either the front or the back.
cb.pop_back();  // 5 is removed.
cb.pop_front(); // 3 is removed.

// Leaving only one element with value = 4.
int d = cb[0];  // d == 4
```

I have used it in my project and did not have any problems with it.